# From deterministic to stochastic LP formulations

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization, linear-programming, stochastic

I am having a hard time understanding the very first example in ["A Tutorial on Stochastic Programming"](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/people/faculty/Alex_Shapiro/TutorialSP.pdf).

More specifically the authors show that one can formulate the stochastic variant of **(1.2)** with **Eq (1.8)**.

### My question:

How should one interpret **(1.8)** (i.e. how do the new inequalities allow us to explore two different scenarios in the problem?)

## The deterministic problem

[image]
[image]

### Stochastic re-formulation

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1.8) is a simple reformulation of the deterministic LP (1.2)  It's still a deterministic LP.   This may be somewhat confusing since the authors are going back forth between a deterministic LP formulation (assuming that $d$ is known) and a stochastic LP formulation (in which we're minimizing the expected value over random values of $d$.)  See (1.9) for the expected value formulation corresponding to the deterministic $d$ formulation in (1.8).

Comment: Thank you Brian! I understand it's still a deterministic LP, what I was/am struggling with is how the new variable $t$ and the new constraints work (i.e. what does $t$ represent, and how do these inequalities help us explore the two scenarios mentioned?)

Comment: This is a standard technique in deterministic LP formulation: You can minimize $\max(a,b)$ by minimizing $t$ subject to the constraints $t \geq a$ and $t \geq b$. Here $t$ is an auxilliary variable whose value ends up being the maximum of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. And how about the equivalence between (1.1) and (1.3)? I also fail that ..

Comment: Well, either $x \geq d$ (with $[x-d]_{+}=x-d$ and $[d-x]_{+}=0$) or $x<d$ (with $[d-x]_{+}=d-x$ and $[x-d]_{+}=0$.)  In the first case where $x \geq d$, the value that you want is $cx+h(x-d)$.  In the second where $x<d$, the value that you want is $cx+b(d-x)$.  So, you take the maximum of $cx+h(x-d)$ and $cx+b(d-x)$.

Comment: Thanks. On the last note: Why is taking the `max` of both expressions to choosing one or the other depending on$ x <d$? (e.g. why not the `min` instead?) 

I think I have seen these types of transformations to piecewise linear equations in inequalities in LP before but never fully understood them.

Comment: The value of the expression in (1.1) is exactly $cx+h(x-d)$ if $x\geq d$, and the value is $cx+b(d-x)$ if $x < d$.   Furthermore, if $x \geq d$, then $cx+h(x-d) \geq cx+b(d-x)$ (keep in mind that $h$ and $b$ are positive.)   On the other hand, $x<d$, then $cx+b(d-x) \geq cx+h(x-d)$.